# Using a F# portable library from a Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, f#

I´m trying to use a portable F# library in my Windows Phone 8 app using Visual Studio 2013 but the compiler cannot resolve dependency to the FSharp.Core.dll version 3.3.1.0.
I have tried to manually add a reference to the FSharp.Core.dll from
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp.NETPortable.
Is F# portable library supported for Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What portable library type are you using? In VS2013, you have to use the "Portable Profile (Legacy)" project type, which corresponds to Profile47. The other project type, "Portable Profile", corresponds to Profile 7, which only supports full .NET and Windows Store apps. Confusingly, in VS2012 the Profile47 project type was named "Portable Profile", which is what VS2013 calls Profile7. You can see an example here of F# being used in a portable library with Windows Phone 8 [here](https://github.com/ovatsus/Apps)

Comment: Thanks! So the F# "Portable" Library is referencing "..\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETCore" and the Lecacy portable library is referencing "..\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETPortable"